# Notice: Undefined variable: click

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

i m facing problem with my code in php and it showing a error
  "Notice: Undefined variable: click"

the code is where it showing notice / error

```
<li class="outer one <?=$click?>">
```

Comment: Are you expecting `$click` to contain a value? what makes you expect that? You need to explain more about what's going on elsewhere in the program than just this; we really don't have enough to go on here to make any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you've declared the variable *$click* above of the code line. This error indicates that the variable is not defined.

To avoid to this error you can use:

```
< li class="outer one [php] if(isset($click)) echo $click; [php]">
```